# Return both a byte array and a message from a web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, servicestack

I have a web service written in *Dotnet* which returns a *byte array* that the *web browser* figures out is *Excel* and lets it be opened.
That is happy path.

But what if I get an error? then I'd like to return an error of some kind, let's say a human readable string.
I could return a different Excel document, one with error message, but would prefer to show it directly in the browser.

Is it even possible?
If so, how would this be implemented on the server and client?

Comment: Totally possible. what version of asp.net are you using.

Comment: @Nkosi The presently latest, 4.0.6

Comment: Do you use asp.net webapi or asp.net mvc?

Comment: @MegaTron [nservicekit](http://www.nservicekit.com)

Comment: @LosManos the last clarification has made it confusing for me. This is how I initially understood your requirement. If valid return byte array with your data that browser knows how to interpret. Else if error, return human readable error to browser. The return both at the same time edit contradicts that requirement? So does that mean that you want a model returned that has byte data and message in one response? because if there is an error, why return byte array? Or did you mean that you want to be able to handle both response types from the same endpoint?

Comment: @Nkosi Good point. It is hard to write good questions... so hard that most of the times writing the question makes me figure out the answer. Not in this case though and I might have polluted my question. I remove the clarifiation to make the question clearer (and will in the future write a separate question to allow people to answer correctly and me to handle out the bonus).

Answer (score 3):

It's a *web service*. This means even though the content of your response is interpretted as  a byte array, it's still wrapped in an HTTP 200 OK response. You don't have to return an HTTP 200 OK. You could return any of the HTTP 4xx or 5xx series instead to indicate an error.

Answer (score 1):

Throw an exception with a message in it. Then catch the exception in your client and put the message to your html.

Answer (score 0):

In case the you can only return byte code, you should return a byte code of an image with an error sign. It would show it on the *web browser*.

Links:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv

Comment: A nice idea but there would be no way of noting the difference at the client (unless one did some bit fiddling that would render another SO question). One would have to do some iframe trick to avoid exchanging the whole interface with said image.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `byte` and `error` in an object and check if `error` is true you can show error message otherwise show excel file.

```
public class YourData
{
 public byte[] arrBytes {get;set;}
 public bool Error {get;set;}
}
```

When you get error set the `Error` to `true` otherwise `false` and return `object` of this class.

You can check if `Error` is `true` you can show error message.

```
if(obj.Error)
 ShowError();
else
 DownloadExcel(obj.arrBytes)
```

Comment: Is this really possible with a javascript client?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: How would the code behind DownloadExcel look? I can foresee problems around character encoding.